# Counting individual word lengths in a string

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
size_t countwords(const char *);
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[] =  "Four score and seven years ago";
    float sum = 0.0;
    char j[10];
    string s;
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(char);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(!isspace(a[i])){
           s += a[i];
        }

        if(isspace(a[i]) and !isspace(a[i + 1])){
            cout << s << " " << s.length() << endl;
            sum += s.length();
            s = "";
        }
    }

    cout << countwords(a);

    return 0;
}

size_t countwords( const char *s )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while ( *s )
    {
        while ( isspace( *s )) ++s;
        if ( *s ) ++count;
        while ( isalnum( *s )) ++s;
    }


    return ( count );
}
```

In the main function, I am able to print each word and it's word length. such as four 4, score 5 etc. I am having trouble handling the last word "ago." I don't know how to account for that. Any help would be appreciated.

Output:

```
Four 4
score 5
and 3
seven 5
years 5
▼  2
6
```

and yeah, don't know why that black triangle is in the output but this is the exact output.

Comment: Although it is OK in the code you have (because all your `char`s are in the ASCII range), note that it can lead to undefined behavior to pass a `char` immediately to `isdigit()` (or any of the other character classification functions): the argument has to be a positive `int` and `char` may be signed (on most platforms it _is_ signed). If you pass a negative value, e.g., when dealing with my second name, you get undefined behavior. Thus, you should always convert the `char` to an `unsigned char`, e.g.: `isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[i]))`.

Answer (score 1):

The terminating NULL character is not considered [whitespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace), so your second `if` condition returns `false` when it encounters the end of the string.

Seems to me the statements within the `for` statement can be simplified to

```
if(!isspace(a[i]) && a[i]){
   s += a[i];
} else {
    cout << s << " " << s.length() << endl;
    sum += s.length();
    s = "";
}
```

Also, breaking the string apart at whitespace can be done easily using an `istringstream`

```
char a[] =  "Four score and seven years ago";

std::istringstream ss(a);
std::string s;

while(ss >> s) {
    std::cout << s << ' ' << s.length() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The string you try to inspect is one character longer than you expect:

```
int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(char);
```

This size includes the terminating null character. If I were to deal with the assignment I would either operator on `char const*` and use the C convention of checking against a terminating null character or I would convert the array into a `std::string` and deal with iterator and check against the end iterator. I also think that the logic you have to check against the end of a word assumes that words are separated by exactly one space.

Your `countwords()` function seems to deal with the C convention. Your `main()` function should check against `a[i]` being null before using `!isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[0]))`: the `countwords()` works because `isspace(0)` and `isalnum(0)` are `false`. However, just because `0` isn't a space it means it is part of a word. You should also consider the terminating null character a word separator, i.e., the condition to report the length of a word should be

```
if(!a[i] || isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string word;
std::istringstream str(a);
while (str >> word) {
    sum += str.length();
    std::cout << word << ' ' << word.length << '\n';
}
```